# Этимология слова "поднатореть"

Tags: этимология

Поднатореть — значит, хорошо чему-то научиться, набить руку. А какая этимология этого слова?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово поднатореть, очевидно, значит "слегка натореть". Глагол натореть менее известен, и означает то же: "приобрести опыт, сноровку". Тайну происхождения этих слов находим в словаре Даля. Натаривать или наторять, торить встарь значило "протаптывать, прокладывать дорогу". Торная дорога - проезженная. Отсюда и переносный смысл. Натореть в деле - "протоптать себе дорожку", знать, что к чему, что делать, куда и зачем идти.

Comment: Только я бы не сказала, что "поднатореть" - это **слегка** натореть. Наоборот, достаточно основательно.

Comment: А мне слышится "поднаторел" - чего-то соображает в каком-то деле, не самый последний.

Comment: >Мы кое в чем поднаторели - мы тарелки бьем весь год,  
Мы на них уже собаку съели, если повар нам не врет.

Comment: Из словаря Ушакова про приставку под-

>>ПОД (3)
см. также [подо] и [подъ], глагольная приставка. Обозначает:

>>5) что целью или результатом действия является прибавление, добавление, напр. подмешать, подлить, подсыпать, подсадить (цветов), подложить (какого–н. кушанья);

 Думаю, тут именно такое значение.

Answer (score 0):

В коммент для [[@Rauf Duseev](/users/1402/rauf-duseev)](/users/1402/rauf-duseev) не укладывается, поэтому формат ответа. Почувствуйте, сколько оттенков народной русской речи! И при чем немцы, татары и проч.?

Фасмер, например, сравнивает только с литовским tarýti, taraũ "говорить, молвить".Это значит - древнейший корень.

*Торить* `Толковый словарь Даля`
что (тереть), прокладывать борозду, тропу, дорожку; протолочить, протоптать; пролагать частым и многим гнетом, боем, накатом, ходьбой. Дороженьки не тори (куда не след), худой славы не клади. Торить тес, выхаживать, прострагивать бороздки. Тореной, торной дороги туда не проложено. В саду дорожки торят, укатывают, или прокладывают и убивают. Торить по прихожим, порога торить, обивать, отаптывать, ходить и ждать, добиваясь чего. Тореные борозды, от наносного валуна, трением выбитые, проносными льдами. Торная ж. сущ. сев. торная дорога, битая, езжалая, укатанная сильной ездой. Чем больше ездить, тем торней дорожка. Где торно, там и просторно. | *Торить мальчика на письме, много упражнять, приучать для навыка; говорить или делать все одно и то же, повторять. | Сиб. мучить, томить, задерживать, волочить или водить. Он меня торил, торил в прихожей! | -* кого, перм. Журить, щунять, школить, бранить, тазать. | Твер. понукать, торопить. Не тори делом: хоть спешко, да смешко. Ториться, быть тори...

Answer (score -3):

Возможно,"торный" как-то связано с татарским  словом "туры",что означает "прямой,ровный,правильно,правдиво". Далее сюда напрашивается английское "true"-"верный,правильный,правдивый" и "truth" -"правда,истина,точность" и немецкое "Treue"-"верность,надёжность" и даже (из немецкого текстильного производства)"ровнота волоса,шерсти".
Фасмер в статье "торный" рассмотрел два разных слова: "торить I "наставлять, внушать", арханг. (Подв.), ср. лит. taryti, tarau "говорить, молвить", tarti, tariu – тоже, далее см. суторить, тороторить." Возможно, сюда же подойдёт выражение "тары-бары"?

Comment: А все это напрашивается по сходству звучания или есть анализ источников, примеры употребления слов?

Comment: Ладно хоть без иудейской Торы обошлись.

 Еще слово "tour" можно посчитать родственным, а остальное – выдумки, мне кажется.